# Robocopy in powershell

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I want to copy the csv files from two different servers and then paste those files at some location on 3rd server.

CSV File location on 1st server is - `E:\HC_Disk\Sample\"+"DiskSpace-"+(Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd)+".csv`

CSV file location on 2nd server - `E:\HC_Disk\Sample\"+"DiskSpace-"+(Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd)+".csv`

I have the script which generates the files everyday. My main concern is to club the two files together in the powershell.

Can you please help me with that. Thanks

Comment: Is this a request to create a code for you or there is your code which is not working properly? If the latter, please share it

Comment: I have not written any code for it so far. If you have any, please share it with me. Thanks!

Comment: When I use the Robocopy command : robocopy \\ServerA\E:\HC_Disk\Sample\"+"DiskSpace-"+(Get-Date-format yyyyMMdd)+".csv\ \\ServerB\E:\Test\   I'll get the error as invalid parameter "-format". Could you please suggest on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to merging two CSVs, assuming the same headers, try below (modify for your filenames/paths):

```
Get-Content file1.csv, file2.csv | Select-Object -Unique | Set-Content mergedfile.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My headers are same in both the files. Also if I have to copy the above two files from two different servers to the 3rd server, how can we use ROBOCOPY for that?

Comment: @HaninderCheema Have you made any effort at all to solve this yourself?

Comment: Copying files from one system to another system is a basic and thoroughly documented process that can be achieved using a plethora of methods, all of which can be found via Google.  Combining the files after copying can be achieved using the code I posted above via PowerShell, or another method if you prefer.